# SQL Syntax error with ms-access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is my query below. The problem im having is that B.REVISED_DATE is a string and B.REVISED_DATE a date and when i try to run the query, i get a data mismatch error. What i am trying to do is change B.REVISED_DATE into a string but I dont remember the exact syntax. I am using microsoft access as the database. Any help would be appreciated.

```
     SELECT A.ICAO, A.RWY, A.REVISED_DATE, B.REVISED_DATE
     FROM RUNWAYS A, RUNWAYS_UPDATABLE B, AIRPORT_CHECKLIST C
     WHERE A.RWYKEY = B.RWYKEY
     AND A.ICAO = C.ICAO
     AND A.REVISED_DATE <> B.REVISED_DATE
     AND TO_CHAR(B.REVISED_DATE) <> C.EMAIL_DATE
     ORDER BY A.ICAO
```

Comment: What format of string are you using for `A.REVISED_DATE`?. YYYYMMDD?, MM/DD/YYYY?, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to turn B.Revised_Date into a string use the Format() function.

```
Format(B.Revised_Date, "Format of date here")
```

Format will convert you date into whatever format you would like to use as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73ctwf33%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

If you are looking to turn B.Revised_Date into a Date use the CDate() function.

```
CDate(B.Revised_Date)
```

So if you are looking to have both of your dates be text then you can do something along these lines.

```
AND Format(A.REVISED_DATE, "MM/dd/yyyy") <> Format(B.REVISED_DATE, "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Or however you want your dates to be formatted.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Access' database engine doesn't support a TO_CHAR function.

If B.REVISED_DATE is Date/Time data type and C.EMAIL_DATE is text, you can use CDate() to get a Date/Time value from C.EMAIL_DATE.

```
B.REVISED_DATE <> CDate(C.EMAIL_DATE)
```

If you prefer to use the text equivalent of B.REVISED_DATE, you could use the CStr() function.  However, unless it is formatted the same as C.EMAIL_DATE, your inequality comparison could be troublesome.  You might be better off using Format() so that REVISED_DATE is formatted the same as EMAIL_DATE

```
Format(B.REVISED_DATE, "mm/dd/yyyy") <> CDate(C.EMAIL_DATE)
```

But seems simpler to me to do the comparison with both as dates, so you needn't be concerned about formatting issues.